# Second Rewriterule not working correctly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to do two things here..

1. redirect http://site.com.au/brand.php?pBrand=THENORTHFACE to http://site.com.au/brand/the-north-face  (this works fine)
2. redirect http://site.com.au/listingbrand.php?pBrand=THENORTHFACE to http://site.com.au/brand/the-north-face  (**this does not work**, when redirecting listingbrand.php?pBrand=DOSH or pBrand=ATKM, they both point back to the first rewrite the-north-face).

How do i make the second rewrite work for each brand? Also, is it correct to repeat the rewrites for each brand?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pBrand=THENORTHFACE$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^brand\.php$ /brand/the-north-face/? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^listingbrand\.php$ /brand/the-north-face/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pBrand=DOSH$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^brand\.php$ /brand/dosh/? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^listingbrand\.php$ /brand/dosh/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pBrand=ATKM$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^brand\.php$ /brand/all-the-kings-men/? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^listingbrand\.php$ /brand/all-the-kings-men/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this rule 3 times:

```
RewriteRule ^listingbrand\.php$ ...
```

Which is **not using** `RewriteCond` since `RewriteCond` is only applicable to very next `RewriteRule`. Actually you don't even need a separate rule since earlier `RewriteRule` can handle both `brand.php` and `listingbrand.php` using OR in regex.

Change your code to this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pBrand=THENORTHFACE$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(brand|listingbrand)\.php$ /brand/the-north-face/? [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pBrand=DOSH$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(brand|listingbrand)\.php$ /brand/dosh/? [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pBrand=ATKM$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(brand|listingbrand)\.php$ /brand/all-the-kings-men/? [R=301,L,NC]
```